# How to add wait in espresso web view cases

Tags: java, webview, ui-automation, android-espresso

```java
onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled())).withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//div[@class='story-metadata-card__title-and-author']"));
```

i running this but its not waiting for 5 sec until view get displayed, even i put 10 sec it will fail without waiting 10 sec,
how to fix and how to use waits as implicitly and explicitly like in selenium

i tried with adding more time i.e 10sec but waiting less than 1sec and failing cases